# Start Activity without it coming to foreground?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an inactivity timer in my app that will do the following after 5 minutes:

```
        Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
        context.startActivity(i);
```

However, if during that 5 minutes I start using another app on my phone, when the 5 minutes is up my app comes to the foreground in front of the other app I was using. How can I still execute the startActivity  but in the background if the app is not active?

Comment: That's not how Activities work. You should be using a notification.

Comment: Use a Service instead to start that Activity.